# Drupal 6: different slideshows for every page, easy in-node editing for end user

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, slideshow

new to Drupal 6. I see a lot of slideshow modules out there, but it seems like most of them require quite a lot of configuration, and would be cumbersome for the user to change later. Some of my pages have sliders, and others have single images in the same spot. I don't want to have a separate node for each slider. The client can't handle that. I would like to have the images uploaded via the attachment section in the page itself, and fields for the image title and alt text. Then I would want to take that and display the image along with the title and alt text as a slideshow, with buttons to switch to previous and next. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The jquery slideshow module almost does what you want, but it doesn't have the next/previous buttons.

I'd recommend just finding a javascript slideshow product that you want to use, and then manually integrate it into a node template.

Recently, I integrated [jqFancyTransitions](http://workshop.rs/projects/jqfancytransitions/) into a Drupal 6 project.  The content type contains a image field, set to allow multiple values.

I installed the library in my theme, then, in the content type specific node template, I added this:

mycontenttype-node.tpl

```
<script src="/sites/all/themes/mytheme/jqFancyTransitions.1.8.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id='ft'>
  <?php foreach ($node->field_my_photo_field as $image): ?>
    <img src="/sites/default/files/imagecache/my_photo_imagecache_preset/<?php print base_path() . str_replace(' ', '%20', $image['filepath']); ?>" alt="" />
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<script>
$('#ft').jqFancyTransitions({ width: 350, height: 300, navigation: true, effect: 'wave' });
</script>
```

Note, I'm using an imagecache preset to crop & scale the images to 350x300, and I had to str_preplace spaces because jqfancytransitions didn't like them.  That's only because it was an easier solution than either requiring users not to use spaces or modifying their file names.